# writing audit records of pre and post values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqldatasource, auditing

I'm currently using an SqlDataSource in ASP.NET/C# to let users insert, delete and update entries in a table/gridview. Every event needs to be written to an audit table.

I have easily implemented inserting and deleting - when inserting, the main info audited is just the parameter values of the insert query (e.Command.Parameters[0].Value.ToString() etc), and deleting is pretty much the same (just getting the ID in the delete query).

But with updating, I need to log which fields were changed and also their old values. How would I do this? As an example, here is the code for the inserting:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Inserting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string fields = e.Command.Parameters[0].Value.ToString() + "," + e.Command.Parameters[1].Value.ToString() + "," + e.Command.Parameters[2].Value.ToString() + "," + e.Command.Parameters[3].Value.ToString() + "," + e.Command.Parameters[4].Value.ToString();
    System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal p = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal as System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal;
    string[] namearray = p.Identity.Name.Split('\\');
    string name = namearray[1];
    string queryString = "INSERT INTO Audit (source, action, item, userid, timestamp) VALUES (@source, @action, @item, @userid, @timestamp)";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("constring - deleted for privacy "))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@source", "Nominal");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@action", "Insert");
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", fields);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", name);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timestamp", DateTime.Now);
        connection.Open();
        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Response.Write(x);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

}

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use SQL Triggers?

Comment: This is a good point as well.  You could implement the logic, no matter which way you end up doing it, through triggers.  You'd have to store a "last changed by user id" column in your main table for this to work, which is the only downside I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

You can save yourself a lot of headache (but not DB space) if you track the current state in your audit log insead of the previous values.  When you insert, throw the original values in your audit table.  Then when you update, throw the newly updated values (whether they've changed or not) in your audit log.  You can roll back to any previous version from here, and you don't have to add any comparison logic for auditing.

Comment: Problem is, the table contains a lot of entries that are already there, and thus would not have any auditting entry. Plus I've been requested to only add the updated fields.

Comment: If you're adding the audit on after the fact, run a query to populate your audit table with current state information, and audit from there forward.  It really depends what the issues are.  If it's a huge table and you need to consolidate space, then that might be a valid request.  If you never have to worry about rolling back or otherwise working programatically with the table, then it's also less of an issue.  If you have to roll back, generate statistics/analysis, or otherwise "do" stuff with your audit log, then more info with some duplication is really the better way to go.